# How to find out the status of an update query

Tags: python, mysql-python

How would I know if the following update executed successfully, right now the statement executes but the table doesn't reflect that.

```
cursor = mysql.cursor()
cursor.execute("""UPDATE foo SET key1 = %s  WHERE id = %s""", (val1, id2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you need to call

```
mysql.commit()
```

for your changes to take effect.

This makes sure that your database operations (you can have multiple) are executed in **one** so called *transaction*. If something goes wrong, you can revert the whole changes.

In one transaction you put stuff that belong together, like adding a new person and setting a reference to that person in another table.

See also the chapter **Insert Operation** on this page (where they use `rollback` in case of an exception): http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to documentation on Source Forge, http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html.

First, as you mentionned, you go with connect, cursor and query execution on this cursor. This is example from doc:

```
import MySQLdb
db=MySQLdb.connect(passwd="moonpie",db="thangs")
c=db.cursor()
max_price=5
c.execute("""SELECT spam, eggs, sausage FROM breakfast
          WHERE price < %s""", (max_price,))
```

**then, you fetch results** using:

```
c.fetchone()
```

Results are returned as a single tuple. If results include more rows, make use of

```
c.fetchall()
```

or

```
c.fetchmany()
```

Answer (score 0):

If autocommit is disabled by default you need to explicitly execute `commit` statement.

`SET autocommit = 1` enables autocommit and every statement will be committed as when they run. Refer [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)